# Excel: where two or more rows contain matching values in two columns (A and B), ensure their values are merged in their column C

Tags: excel

I have three columns and a few thousand rows. Column A contains data type "name", column B contains data type "number", and column C contains data type "source". I have duplicates of "name/number" matches from multiple sources and I need to de-duplicate these without losing "source" attribution in column C. If I can get them merged, or even just copied up next to column C in columns D and E so I can merge them, that'll save a ton of time compared to "doing this manually because I've spent 30 years not learning visual basic before I needed it."

For reference, I want to turn this:

| name | number | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| shoe | 1111 | book 1 |
| car | 2222 | book 1 |
| nailpolish | 3333 | book 1 |
| dog | 4444 | book 1 |
| shoe | 1111 | book 2 |
| car | 2222 | book 2 |
| nailpolish | 3333 | book 2 |
| dog | 4444 | book 2 |
| dog | 4444 | book 3 |

Into this:

| name | number | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| shoe | 1111 | book 1, book 2 |
| car | 2222 | book 1, book 2 |
| nailpolish | 3333 | book 1, book 2 |
| dog | 4444 | book 1, book 2, book 3 |

Comment: And you won't need VBA for this either.... you can do another year without it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really all it is, just a few steps in PowerQuery:

- Select your data and load into PQ
- In PW, select "Source" column and open the "Group By" function on the Home tab.
- In the advanced screen, group by columns "name" and "number". Choose an appropriate name for your column and group on all rows.
- Now in the top, click the "View" tab and open the "Advanced Editor".
- You'll see the generated M-code. We are going to make a simple adjustment to this code, there should be a line that says: `#"Grouped Rows"= .....`. We are going to swap this line for:

  ```
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"name", "number"}, {{"Grouped", each Text.Combine([source],", "), type text}})
  ```
- Save the code and see the changes in your screen

[image]

- Exit PQ while saving your changes.

[image]

Comment: Difficulty Level: I'm working from an organizationally-owned computer and can't export the data or download any fun tools like Power Query. I honestly didn't even think to say that bit though.

Comment: Edit: Ahhh, I *do* have powerquery! Playing now!

Comment: YES! Thank you. I'm down to 7k entries from over 11k. So much better! You're the best, and now I know Power Query exists and where to find it.

Comment: @trotter. There you go. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left if it helped you out.